# In Entity Framework, how do I create an Association Property in code?

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I would like to create an Association Property with the following setup:

```
public class ClassType1{
    [Key]
    public int type1_ID { get;set; }
    public int type2_ID { get;set; }  // In database, this is a foreign key linked to ClassType2.type2_ID
    public ClassType2 type2Prop { get;set; }
}

public class ClassType2{
    [Key]
    public int type2_ID { get;set; }
}
```

My problem is that type2Prop can't find it's foregin key.  It is trying to look for "type2Prop_ID", which does not exist, when it should really be looking for "type2_ID".  Here is the error I get:

```
{"Invalid column name 'type2Prop_ID'."}
```

How do I tell it which property to use as ClassType2's key?

Comment: are you using EF code first?

Comment: I think so, but I am not sure.  This is the problem with our industry.  I never had any formal education in EF because when I was back in school, EF didn't exist yet!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try a `ForeignKeyAttribute` on `type2Prop`:

```
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.Schema;

public class ClassType1
{
  [Key]
  public int type1_ID { get; set; }

  public int type2_ID { get; set; }  // In database, this is a foreign key linked to ClassType2.type2_ID

  [ForeignKey("type2_ID")]
  public virtual ClassType2 type2Prop { get; set; }
}

public class ClassType2
{
  [Key]
  public int type2_ID { get;set; }
}
```

You can also do it using the Fluent API in a refactor-proof way (i.e. if you change the name of your property in the future, the compiler will let you know you have to change the mapping as well).  It's a bit uglier for simple cases like this, but it's also more robust.  In your `DbContext` class, you could add something like:

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
  modelBuilder.Entity<ClassType1>().HasRequired(x => x.type2Prop)
                                   .WithMany()
                                   .HasForeignKey(x => x.type2_ID);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public class ClassType1{
    [Key]
    public int type1_ID { get;set; }
    [ForeignKey("type2Prop")]
    public int type2_ID { get;set; }  // In database, this is a foreign key linked to ClassType2.type2_ID
    public ClassType2 type2Prop { get;set; }
}

public class ClassType2{
    [Key]
    public int type2_ID { get;set; }
}
```

Comment: Please add a bit more substance in your answer. Code-only answers are usually discouraged.